# browse or select file button disable in iphone safari browser

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I want to know why **`select file`** or **`choose file`** button is disable when a web page is view in iphone safari.

Can anyone tell explain me why this happens is there any way to enable it ??

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you can't upload files from your iPhone?

Comment: Because the iPhone file system is set up in such a way that Mobile Safari won't be able to access your iPod libraries, iBooks, app data and other files.

Comment: is there any way to enable it ??

Comment: [Should I not flag a rhetorical question posted as an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131959)