# How to upload a file with JQueryMobile for an iphone/ipad?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ios, jquery-mobile

I have just started looking at JqueryMobile and want to know if the following is possible?

I want to be able to select a file (similar to  in html) and then show some sort of dialogue that allows me to browse to a "folder" and select the file. It would then be up to me to send some sort of AJAX command to upload it to the server (where I am using Asp.net MVC 2)

Since I do not have access to an iPhone or iPad, I was told that I would only have access to the documents folder.

JD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>You can't [upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616742/browse-or-select-file-button-disable-in-iphone-safari-browser) files using Safari and therefore JQueryMobile.</s>

You can upload with ios 6 Safari as it now supports file upload from the gallery and some support for [media capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/)

Comment: Any other browsers that would allow me to do it on an iPad or iPhone?

Comment: @JD: Sadly not, since iOS does not allow access to the file system via the web browser, unless it's either unlocked, or a bug. Neither of which use cases will be the standard. Also I'm not aware of a central documents folder/repository on the iOS.

Comment: This leaves a major whole in my web app as I need this. Any news of Safari allowing this in the imminent future? Also, why do safari not allow it, even for a central repository?

Comment: @JD - have you thought about local storage - see bonus section of this page - http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/ - it may or may not suit your needs

Comment: @Nicholas: Didn't quite get it, how does local storage help? If a user has images say on his sd card, could we access those files and then update these to the web server?

Comment: @JD - in that scenario it won't help. I wasn't quite sure of your use case. It's a security issue - the browser/jquery does not have access to your file system whether on a computer or a smart phone. You may have to create a native application instead as it can have access to the file system.

Comment: To any who come in the future - file upload is now supported with iOS 6

Comment: @Kevin - changed the answer to include updated support for file upload

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's possible to send files, but take a look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/). It gives access to filesystem to apps written with html/js

Just to be clear - Phonegap's support for iOS is rather fresh at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, with Safari in the soon to arrive iOS 6, file upload works great. I've been doing some mobile web app development with the beta version, using the `<input type="file" />`, and it works great!